# Prove that given any two consecutive integers, one is even and the other is odd.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, first-order-logic, solution-verification, natural-deduction

*Symbolization key*:

- $E(x)$: x is even.
- $O(x)$: x is odd

$
\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
\def\Ae#1{\qquad\mathbf{\forall E} \: #1 \\}
\def\Ai#1{\qquad\mathbf{\forall I} \: #1 \\}
\def\Ee#1{\qquad\mathbf{\exists E} \: #1 \\}
\def\Ei#1{\qquad\mathbf{\exists I} \: #1 \\}
\def\R#1{\qquad\mathbf{R} \: #1 \\}
\def\ii#1{\qquad\mathbf{\to I} \: #1 \\}
\def\ie#1{\qquad\mathbf{\to E} \: #1 \\}
\def\be#1{\qquad\mathbf{\leftrightarrow E} \: #1 \\}
\def\bi#1{\qquad\mathbf{\leftrightarrow I} \: #1 \\}
\def\qi#1{\qquad\mathbf{=I}\\}
\def\qe#1{\qquad\mathbf{=E} \: #1 \\}
\def\ne#1{\qquad\mathbf{\neg E} \: #1 \\}
\def\IP#1{\qquad\mathbf{IP} \: #1 \\}
\def\x#1{\qquad\mathbf{X} \: #1 \\}
$
$
\fitch{1.\, \forall x(E(x) \leftrightarrow \exists y(x = 2y)) \\2.\, \forall x(O(x) \leftrightarrow \exists y(x = 2y + 1)) }{
 \fitch{3.\, E(a)}{
 4.\, E(a) \leftrightarrow \exists y(a = 2y) \Ae{1}
 5.\, \exists y(a = 2y) \be{4,3}
 \fitch{6.\, a = 2k}{
 7.\, a + 1 = a + 1 \qi{}
 8.\, a + 1 = 2k + 1 \qe{6,7}
 9.\, \exists y(a + 1 = 2y + 1) \Ei{8}
 10.\, O(a + 1) \leftrightarrow \exists y(a + 1 = 2y + 1) \Ae{1}
 11.\, O(a + 1) \be{10,9}
}\\
12.\, O(a + 1) \Ee{5,6-11}
}\\
\fitch{13.\, O(a+1)}{
 14.\, O(a+1) \leftrightarrow \exists y(a + 1 = 2y + 1) \Ae{2}
 15.\, \exists y(a + 1 = 2y + 1) \be{13,14}
 \fitch{16.\, a + 1 = 2k + 1}{
 17.\, a = 2k \qquad \text{aritmethic}\\
 18.\, \exists y(a = 2y) \Ei{17}
 19.\, E(a) \leftrightarrow \exists y(a = 2y) \Ae{1}
 20.\, E(a) \be{19,18}
}\\
21.\, E(a) \Ee{15,16-20}
}\\
22.\, E(a) \leftrightarrow O(a+1) \bi{3-12,13-21}
23.\, \forall x(E(x) \leftrightarrow O(x+1)) \Ai{22}
}
$

Is the conclusion correctly symbolized using quantifiers ? Is this proof correct ?

Comment: The conclusion is correct.  The proof is so elaborate that it's nearly useless.

Comment: Thanks. It is a _formal proof_. Every step is justified with a rule of inference. That’s why it is so long.

Comment: A most obnoxiously useless, time wasting neofad discriminatory of older, more useful and efficient formal proof styles.

Comment: What's the rationale for it ? I do not think it is useless. Perhaps it is useful to train reasoning and logic skills.